# UITableViewRowAction change font and/or size

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uitableviewrowaction

I have a UITableView with cells having some UITableViewRowActions. Our mockup uses a smaller font and a narrower UITableViewRowAction button. Is it possible to change the font and/or size of an UITableViewRowAction in any way?

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html) states it's impossible, and therefore I'm asking whether there is another way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` is made up of a `backgroundView` and a `contentView`, which lays over the `backgroundView` what you can do is add `UIButton`s as `subView`s to your `backgroundView` and add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` over the cell. So when you pan the cell horizontally only `contentView` moves, `UIButton`s get exposed. So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *myCell;
        myCell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"];

   //adding button to a view that is added as the backgroundview
   UIView *cellBackgroundUtilityView=[[UIView   alloc]initWithFrame:myCell.frame];
   [cellBackgroundUtilityView addSubview:<your button>]
   [myCell setBackgroundView: cellBackgroundUtilityView]

   //adding a gesture recognizer
   UIPanGestureRecognizer *panningCell=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourPanningTableViewCellMethod:)];
   [panningCell setDelegate:self];
   [myCell addGestureRecognizer:panningCell];
}
```

when the gesture recognizer will be active this method will be called

```
-(void) yourPanningTableViewCellMethod:(id)sender
{
 // gesture recognizer is active
 UIPanGestureRecognizer* recognizer=(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    UITableViewCell *tableCell=(UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;

 //moving the contentView horizontally according to pan
 [tableCell.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake([recognizer translationInView:self.view].x, tableCell.contentView.frame.origin.y, tableCell.frame.size.width, tableCell.frame.size.height)];
}
```

when button's selector is called

```
-(void)yourBackgroundViewButtonWasPressed
{
 // button was pressed
 // move content view of the cell back to origin
 [tableCell.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, tableCell.contentView.frame.origin.y, tableCell.frame.size.width, tableCell.frame.size.height)];

 //do your stuff
}
```